# Is the macOS Terminal only ever in English?

Tags: macos, terminal, international

In Windows, string parsing in the command-line is a crapshoot, both for Batch and PowerShell. Essential command-line tools like `fsutil` and `dcdiag` return their output in strings which are internationalised to the language of the OS installation, making scriptwriting in a one-size-fits-all capacity almost impossible without factoring in support for every single language's choice of wording and formatting.

Wherever possible I write in PowerShell (to return *objects* instead of *strings*) and use the WMI to return non-localised enumerators I translate myself via lookup tables; there will always be some tools, however, that serve as the only means on a device to gather the information required.

I am now writing a script for macOS invoking (in this instance) the `csrutil` tool.
Like many *nix utilities its output is in string format. Running it produces the following output:

```
System Integrity Protection status: unknown (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
    Apple Internal: disabled
    Kext Signing: disabled
    Filesystem Protections: disabled
    Debugging Restrictions: disabled
    DTrace Restrictions: disabled
    NVRAM Protections: disabled
    BaseSystem Verification: enabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.
```

Somehow the internet does not contain any knowledge on this subject I could find, so:

#### How aggressive are Apple in internationalising terminal output?

This is less a question about Bash or ZSH as I know these are always English, but macOS is notorious for creating incompatible Apple-specific forks of POSIX tools; further, as demonstrated above, there are many Apple-developed command-line tools intended for managing macOS systems. Should I assume these will have been translated into at least German and procure a macOS device with the German language installed on it? Or is everything just always in English?

In general, I am asking how much internationalisation I should expect from Apple-forged command-line tools.

Comment: What does this mean: “How aggressive are Apple in internationalising terminal output?” Seems like the opposite question of the title: “Is the macOS Terminal only ever in English?” The title is clear and understandable, but “How aggressive are Apple in…” is a bit confusing because it implies that Apple is either aggressive or passive in their efforts to get non-English language options into the Terminal. Is your goal to simply have it _all_ be in English so scripts don’t break in other locales? Or something else?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am simply asking how much internationalisation I should expect from Apple-forged command-line tools. My background is in Windows, where (at least) the German release of the software could be said to be "very aggressive" with its internationalisation, hindering string searching. Aggression in this sense is not a bad thing; perhaps a word like "comprehensive" or "rigorous" would have been more appropriate.

Comment: You don't need a German device to try macOS in German, a typical macOS installation includes all the translations. You set the preferred language(s) in the Language & Region panel in System Preferences.app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now, most of those (non-.app) system administration tools are English only. This facilitates parsing of the output.

You can for example try to examine binaries like that:

```
strings /usr/bin/csrutil | less
```

in this case, there are no translations present in the binary

You might consider to set `$LANG` or `$LC_MESSAGES` locale (just *locally* in your scripts using `env`), like in

```
env LC_MESSAGES=C /usr/bin/csrutil
```

`env` will launch `csrutil` with the the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable set to "C", which is a special setting translating to "act as if this program has not been localised".
This will cause English output for this session but will have no effect on your system in general.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. How certain are you that any tool (in this instance csrutil) will have all languages' strings embedded within it and that there are not separate tools available?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how macOS does this, but on Linux and BSDs the translations wouldn't be present in the binary itself, but e.g. in separate `<lang>.po` files (if the program uses gettext/NLS, which many CLI apps do). Still, it is indeed better to explicitly request `LC_MESSAGES=C` than hope the translation situation doesn't change...

Comment: There is still possibility for an external translation layer... - aah, @user1686 has the details, thank you. But changing the locale hopefully should overcome that.

Comment: Would you be willing to edit/re-post your answer to accommodate that information? I'm not sure how to request `LC_MESSAGES=C`.

Comment: absolutely yes, one moment please!

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how I'd do the opposite to test? For example, I'm trying `env LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8 ping 8.8.8.8` but it's just giving me the messages in English. Is this because I'm misusing the command or because `ping` doesn't give localised output?

Comment: @seagull You’re using the environment variable correctly, it’s just that most of the CLI tools on macOS just don’t have translations. Apple is very much a _GUI first_ company in terms of their mentality, they assume that normal users will never touch the terminal or CLI, so they don’t really do much to make it nice for interactive usage.

Comment: That's a very diplomatic way to word similar opinions for Apple and their "software" that I have, @AustinHemmelgarn. Thanks for the clarification.